# Difference between Color.red and Color.RED

Tags: java, colors

What's the real difference between definitions for `setXxx(Color.red)` and `setXxx(Color.RED)`?

I've found the following explanation on the web. Is it all about naming conventions?

> Java originally defined a few color constant names in lowercase, which violated  the naming rule of using uppercase for constants. They are available in all versions of Java: Color.black, Color.darkGray, Color.gray, Color.lightGray, Color.white, Color.magenta, Color.red, Color.pink, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.cyan, Color.blue
>
> Java 1.4 added the proper uppercase names for constants: Color.BLACK, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.WHITE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.PINK, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE

Comment: The coding convention for constants is UPPER_CASE. Using upper case indicates its a constant.

Comment: `RED` is at least three time redder than `red`. And much angrier.

Comment: The coding convention for constants is UPPER_CASE, but note that RED is not actually a constant, because it's a Color, not a primitive nor an enum. I think the definition of constants people use when talking about code is inconsistent with the definition of constant according to the JLS.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There's the code itself:

```
public final static Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);

public final static Color RED = red;
```

The upper case letters were introduced in JDK 1.4 (to conform to its naming convention, stating that constants **must** be in upper-case).

In essence, there are no difference at all (except letter casing).

---

If I want to really be brave, Oracle might go wild and remove constants that is lower-cased, but then that would break all other code that's written pre-JDK 1.4. You never know, I would suggest sticking to uppercase letters for constants. It first has to be deprecated though (as mentioned by Andrew Thompson).

Comment: It irritates me that it took so long (1.4) for Sun to concede that the lower case equivalents did not match common Java nomenclature for constants.

Answer (score 21):

There is really no difference. See the `Color` class:

```
/**
 * The color red.  In the default sRGB space.
 */
public final static Color red       = new Color(255, 0, 0);

/**
 * The color red.  In the default sRGB space.
 * @since 1.4
 */
public final static Color RED = red;
```

Answer (score 1):

Java defined some color constant names in lowercase, which violated the naming rule of using uppercase for constants.
Heres the code for the color red:

```
public final static Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
```

Later on they made the same colors but in uppercase.

```
public final static Color RED = red;
```

So there is really no difference. They are all the same, as you can tell by the code.

```
public final static Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
public final static Color RED = red;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please post answers to fresh questions. This question was asked in 2011 and also it was answered and the answer was marked as accepted. Read new questions and try to help those people. Cheers.