# What's the difference between Color.black and Color.BLACK?

Tags: java, colors, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Color.red and Color.RED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281180/difference-between-color-red-and-color-red)

I have seen that the Java class `java.awt.Color` contains couples of fields with the same name, once in capital letters and once not. For example: `Color.black` and `Color.BLACK`. Is there a difference?

**edit:**

… and if not, why are there two of them?

Comment: Oops, didn't see that one. Sorry, it is in fact a duplicate!

Comment: maybe not, no votes (+1/-1) for you +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just take a look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#black):

```
public static final Color black
```

> The color black. In the default sRGB space.

---

```
public static final Color BLACK
```

> The color black. In the default sRGB space. **Since: 1.4**

No, there is no difference.

Both of them exist because `black` has been introduced with the [`Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class, then they realized that it wasn't following naming convention so they added the capitalized version (you can see **since 1.4** written). They didn't remove the old ones to not break any < 1.4 code.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference excpet that `Color.BLACK` follows the naming conventions for static final fields.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see in source there is no difference

```
public final static Color black     = new Color(0, 0, 0);
public final static Color BLACK = black;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference , however since Capitalizations are not enforced by Java compilers, but it is considered bad style to violate them . SO color.BLACK should be preferred to add to the readability .

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the fields of the `Color` class there is no difference at all.

1) [Color.black](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#black)

2) [Color.BLACK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#BLACK)