# Why does java.awt.Color have two variables for every Color?

Tags: java, variables, colors, awt

An excerpt from [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html):

```
...
/**
 * The color white.  In the default sRGB space.
 */
public final static Color white     = new Color(255, 255, 255);

/**
 * The color white.  In the default sRGB space.
 * @since 1.4
 */
public final static Color WHITE = white; // My comment: THE SAME!!??
...
```

As you can see from the above extract, the `Color` `white` is assigned to **two** variables namely [`Color#WHITE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#WHITE) and [`Color#white`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#white) this is also the same case for:

```
 - black     (and BLACK)
 - blue      (and BLUE)
 - cyan      (and CYAN)
 - darkGray  (and DARK_GRAY)
 - gray      (and GRAY)
 - green     (and GREEN)
 - lightGray (and LIGHT_GRAY)
 - magenta   (and MAGENTA)
 - orange    (and ORANGE)
 - pink      (and PINK)
 - red       (and RED)
 ->white     (and WHITE)<-discussed
 - yellow    (and YELLOW)
```

Initially, I used to think that each color had two names for a reason. But when I checked the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Color.java), I came to know that *both of them have the same value*!

---

I want to know **why is there such a provision for having two variables for every color?**

**Is there any specific reason (be it historic, practical, etc.) for such usage?**

And finally, **which of the two to use in our applications?**:

```
// THIS?:
Color newC = Color.white;

// OR THIS?:
Color newC = Color.WHITE;
```

Comment: [see my quesstion about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281180/difference-between-color-red-and-color-red)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variables were changed according to Java conventions which says constants to be uppercase only. The lowercase are still there for compatibility and have the same value.

To follow Java conventions you should always use the uppercase constants like:

```
Color.RED
```

Comment: Does it mean they'll be removed in a later release?

Comment: I don't think they will be removed anytime soon since they would be marked as deprecated first.

Comment: But it strikes me... now that `enums` are in practise, why don't they replace the variables with `enum constants`?

Comment: @ambigram_maker:- As I have already mentioned in my answer that this convention is followed since JDK1.4 but it is hard to say that when Oracle is going to deprecate it.!

Comment: @ambigram_maker I don't think an enum would quite fit in this case since you not only have the constants but you can also instantiate your own Color with different values. The constants only represent a set of these possible options.

Comment: So I guess it'll be more troublesome?

Comment: Like this they have brought in the new variables according to the conventions without breaking backwards compatibility and minimal code redundancy. Since backwards-compatibility is highly regarded in java they won't make drastic changes that would destroy it.

Comment: *"..is followed since JDK1.4"*  I think it was actually 1.4.2 which saw the first appearance of the upper case variants.  They were not available in 1.4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Because they wanted to follow a convention(since  **JDK 1.4**) which says  constants should be used in uppercase only. So you should prefer to use:

```
Color.RED
```

Answer (score 3):

If you see the source code of Color.java, you will find that both are same only.

```
public final static Color white     = new Color(255, 255, 255);
```

and Since 1.4

```
 public final static Color WHITE = white;
```

Just because of Java specification which says constant (final static) should be in upper case, a `WHITE` constant is introduced.

**UPDATE:**

> By convention, the names of constant values are spelled in uppercase
>   letters. If the name is composed of more than one word, the words are
>   separated by an underscore (_).

Comment: Happy triple figure rep.  :)